# Passing in matrix to glsl shader

Tags: opengl, graphics, matrix, glsl, shader

So if a given mesh comes with a given matrix transformation and I want to use that transformation in my vertex shader, how do I use it once it's already passed in. Let's call it "myMatrix".

So what I'm doing is:

```
    varying vec3 modelPos = (gl_ModelViewMatrix * myMatrix * vec4(positionIn, 1)).xyz;
    gl_Position = (gl_ProjectionMatrix * vec4(modelPos, 1));
```

where "positionIn" is the passed in vertex.

This doesn't seem to be working though (Nothing shows up to the screen). The object renders normally if I take out "myMatrix" but then of course it doesn't have its transformation applied to it.

Comment: It's hard to know what the problem is when you don't tell us the actual contents of *all* of those matrices.

Comment: gl_ModelViewMatrix and gl_ProjectionMatrix are predefined matrices provided by glsl. The only "unique" matrix here is myMatrix, which can be a rotation, translation, etc.

Comment: I'm well aware of what they mean; I asked what the *contents* of them are. Like specific numbers. More to the point, why are you trying to inject a matrix into the computation if you're already using the fixed-function matrices?

Comment: I don't understand why you need the actual numbers. All I'm asking is if I want to apply a random matrix which can be anything from a rotation to a translation, etc how do I insert it along with the other matrices? Is the order I have above correct? Am I using the wrong glsl matrices? gl_modelView and gl_Projection only change the coordinate system of the vertex but don't do any other operations on them, which is why I want to pass in my matrix.

Comment: "*how do I insert it along with the other matrices?*" In order to accomplish what? What does this matrix represent? What are you trying to do by inserting this matrix? And if you can't answer what coordinate transforms a matrix represents, then you aren't ready to be using it at all.

Comment: I already said let's pretend its a rotation matrix or a translation matrix. It doesn't matter what the actual numbers are. How would I include a rotation matrix here in order to rotate properly?

Comment: If the question you're asking is how to get the values from _myMatrix_ into your shader, assuming the matrix doesn't need to change while rendering the primitives in the mesh, then you're like looking for a _uniform_ variable.  You declare them in your shader using the keyword `uniform`, e.g., in your case `uniform mat4 myMatrix;`  You then populate that variable by calling `glUniformMatrix4fv` (as one example, there are other ways) before engaging your shader.

Comment: To radical: that's not my question. I already have 'myMatrix' passed into the shader. I'm asking how to use it once it's inside the shader. If I want to rotate my object for instance and 'myMatrix' is a rotation matrix, what do I need to do?

Comment: @user1782677: How do you use it *to do what*? There are *many* legitimate ways to use a matrix, and each of those uses of the matrix depends on what you want that matrix to actually *do* to the object. Do you want to rotate the object in object space? In camera space? In post-projection space? In some other space? What are you trying to *do* with this matrix and what visual result do you want to see?

Comment: does it work if `myMatrix` is an [identity matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_matrix)? That's a good test to start with

Answer (score 2):

As everyone keeps trying to tell you, the multiplication order depends on what your matrix represents.  You say "rotation".  We say "rotation in what coordinate frame?"

```
varying vec3 modelPos = (gl_ModelViewMatrix * myMatrix * vec4(positionIn, 1)).xyz;
```

In the code you quote, `myMatrix` is closest to your raw vertex position.  So if that was a rotation of 45 degrees around the x-axis, it would be a 45 degree rotation around the x-axis of *object-space*, where the origin is (0,0,0) relative to your stored vertex positions and the axis are similarly the natural axis of vertex positions.

If you reverse the order such that you have:
    varying vec3 modelPos = (myMatrix  * gl_ModelViewMatrix * vec4(positionIn, 1)).xyz;

Now the ModelView transform happens first because it's closest to your raw, object-space vertex position.  So now `myMatrix` is operating in *camera-space*, where the origin is at the camera and the z-axis is along the camera's view vector.

If you wanted to rotate around the x-axis of *world-space*, then there is no easy way to do that in the vertex shader while still using the old-style fixed-function transform matrices.  With the fixed function matrices, you would apply your custom matrix to the ModelView matrix in software while you are setting it up.

The more modern approach is to pass all your matrices in via custom uniforms and not use the built-ins.  So you could pass in the model, view, and projection transforms independently and insert your custom matrix in between Model and View.

Answer (score 0):

Just declare it as uniform mat4 myMatrix before declaring the vert shader's main() function